how to remove page scrolling from the top and bottom so that the scrolling is not noticeable when the content reaches the edge of the page
the appearance of the scroll on the page, so that the scroll is not noticeable when the content reaches the edge of the page
tried through overview:hidden, also through the library import { RemoveScroll } from 'react-remove-scroll'. used react. now overflow is       overflowY: 'auto',
